# Suppressing the "Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS" message

Tags: java, rhel

I'm using _JAVA_OPTIONS to set some defaults for Java on RHEL. It works fine but now every time I start java I get the following message

> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -foo -bar -baz

is it possible to keep the options but suppress the display of this message.

Comment: try to define `_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=$HOME/tmp"` as an environment variable. [Source](http://www.coderanch.com/t/428867/Linux-UNIX/Picked-up-JAVA-OPTIONS)

Comment: This still shows the "Picked up"  message, for example:

`JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=$HOME/tmp" java`
 gives me 
`Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/foouser/tmp`

Comment: I [re-asked and answered](http://superuser.com/q/585695/67265) the question on superuser, I hope it’s useful.

Comment: Don't put passwords here. Rather use this for general options and passwords should be passed as parameters to scripts.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From looking at the relevant source code ([arguments.cpp in openjdk, line 2492](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~gbenson/zero-11-hotspot/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp.html)), there is no way to control the output of this message.

The only thing I could say is that it is printed to `stderr`. So you could wrap your commands to redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` (if there wasn't anything else you cared about on `stderr`).

- Or write a `java` wrapper script which filtered out this message.
- Or submit a feature request to the openjdk project, although this won't solve your immediate problem.

Comment: syntax for suppressing the options output: http://superuser.com/questions/585695/suppressing-the-picked-up-java-options-message

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039152 won't fix

Answer (score 13):

Where is `_JAVA_OPTIONS` being set? In your .bashrc?

Use an alias instead, e.g.

```
alias java="`which java` -Dwhatever"
```

---

Actually, it is not necessary to know where it is being set to make this work:

```
_SILENT_JAVA_OPTIONS="$_JAVA_OPTIONS"
unset _JAVA_OPTIONS
alias java='java "$_SILENT_JAVA_OPTIONS"'
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't answer the question. =)

Comment: It is being set as part of a wrapper script which runs java with a sensible minimum amount of memory if the options isn't already set. Therefore I don't think I can use this solution.

Comment: @Jan yes it does, as the question was asked. I didn't know the deeper context. And it works for me as I had the same problem and resolved it (seeing this unwanted message when running java programs in bash), so I thought I'd pass it on. Maybe useful to someone with my particular circumstances going by the same question.

Comment: 'unset _JAVA_OPTIONS' was all I'm looking for ..