# Jmeter on Windows 10(Master) is not receiving test results from Slave

Tags: jmeter

I am performing remote distributed testing through JMeter on my windows machine as master (Windows 10) and amazon Linux as the slave. I have configured jmeter.properties with client.rmi.localport and server.rmi.localport on both.

All configurations are fine as I can connect and remote start my JMeter server.

But I am not able to see the test results on my master machine.

I could see the results on Windows 7 with same configurations in jmeter.properties.
Also, I saw one more process `JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,127.0.0.1:****)` & `JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,127.0.0.1:****)` on Windows 7 but can't see these on Windows 10.

Please resolve for this.

Answer (score 3):

Being not enough telepathic unfortunately I cannot identify and fix your issue remotely. However here are few possible workarounds:

1. Copy JMeter and Java folders from Windows 7 to Windows 10 machine.
2. [Enable extra debug logging](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) on Windows 7, Windows 10 and remote JMeter engines by adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   log_level.jmeter=DEBUG
   ```

   and compare the output in both cases
3. You can also try adding the next line to *system.properties* file

   ```
   java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
   ```

   as Windows 10 might be using IPv6 addresses by default or it may be something due to [dual stack clash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648392/why-do-i-need-java-net-preferipv4stack-true-only-on-some-windows-7-systems)
4. And finally, JMeter automatically [removes response data from successful samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#sendermode), it means you won't be able to see anything apart pass/fail flag and some timings. If you need to see the response data as well - add the next line to *user.properties* file on remote engines:

   ```
   mode=Standard
   ```

   - JMeter restart is required to pick any property change up
   - See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter properties and ways of working with them

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

I had the logs enabled and after posting the question I found one of the java class which JMeter is invoking is corrupted and hence I am unable to see the response on Master.

I re-installed JAVA JDK and it worked fine.