# Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M message

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to teach myself java with online content, so I installed `Netbeans` after trying to make `eclipse` work with no success.

When I try to compile some code while following a tutorial, a window pops up with an error message saying that one or more files were compiled with errors and asks if I still want to run it.

I click yes and nothing happens except that I get this message:

> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M

I searched several posts, some of them mentioned the same message but none of it made much sense to me, I'm still a newbie to this.

Let me know if you need more info,

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683715/suppressing-the-picked-up-java-options-message)

Answer (score 0):

Remove JAVA_OPTION setting from your environment variable in system settings. It will work.