# How to remove error Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M?

Tags: java, classpath

In java program, When I try to compile some code  it creates an error
I get this message:

`Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M`

what type of error is this the page [Suppressing the "Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS" message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683715/suppressing-the-picked-up-java-options-message) 
cannot solve problem ,how to change system variable in windows 7 ??

Comment: If you have a variable in Windows Environment Variables called _JAVA_OPTIONS, just delete it and it should fix the issue.

Comment: Why this variable will be in the environment variable? Is this set by Java?

Comment: No.  It was set by something else.  Users / applications should not use this option.  The warning printed because this mechanism can lead to security-related problems.   (Unfortunately, they can't get rid of it entirely because that would break things.)

Answer (score 10):

Go to my computer and right click on top of that and click on properties,  a new window will open like below.

[image]

then click on advanced system setting

[image]

then click on environment variable and delete _JAVA_OPTIONS from user variable
and then try again.

Answer (score 2):

Part of my original answer was truncated, so here is the edited answer:

From the Start Buttong, search for System, then launch "System" from your search results.  In the new window, select Advanced System Settings. A new window will open, select the Advanced tab, then click on the Environment button.  In this new window, select _Java_Options, in the user variables and then click on Delete. If the lower section, System Variables, is greyed out and you cannot delete _Java_Options there, you will need to log on as an administrator, or attempt to run the "System" command as Administrator.

Answer (score 2):

You have to delete your environment variable named "_JAVA_OPTIONS" going to system, advance settings. Save, close your project and restart.

Answer (score -1):

Please check your **JDK**  version. Maybe you need to change or upgrade your **JDK** version.