# Android Studio - Problem with trying to increase Xmx

Tags: android-studio, memory, out-of-memory

I tried to run my project and it appears that I did not allocate enough memory so I go to VM options and upgraded, and the error still appears, when it appears like in the screenshot I put my value oh Xmx and select shutdown.

What can I do if it does not change after that?

Screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: "Making it bigger" isn't necessarily the same as "making it big enough".

Answer (score -1):

It seems that I had and *JAVA_OPTIONS* error apering all the time but I didn't see it, i just deleted the Java Options from users and systems following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227977/how-to-remove-error-picked-up-java-options-xmx512m)