# Heroku giving 'Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS', and setting JMX to 'true' is not stopping it

Tags: heroku

The way my program works, which is a java runtime for discord, it displays the console output from a java program. The issue is that right now, the program picks up the 'Picked up' message, then picks up nothing else. I'd like to get rid of this message. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku sets JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS for you dyno. You can read about it [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#environment)

It seems you can't really remove the message. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683715/suppressing-the-picked-up-java-options-message) is a question with more information about that.

But the message is sent to stderr. Maybe ignore that?