# Android Studio creates files in Dropbox folder (\Dropbox\.AndroidStudioPreview)

Tags: android, windows, environment-variables, android-studio

Android Studio puts .AndroidStudioPreview folder directly in to my Dropbox folder.
I don't want them there since they are getting synced every time.

Does anyone know how to change the settings-path of Android Studio?

ANDROID_HOME var shows correct path:

```
C:\Users\Admin>set ANDROID_HOME

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Admin\Dev\Android
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the default location for your settings by editing `idea.properties` file located at

```
$STUDIO_INSTALLATION_DIR\bin\idea.properties
```

You need to edit following properties in file. Follow the comments in the file in order to change the defaults, make sure to un-comment the properties you are setting to bring them in action :

```
idea.config.path
idea.system.path
idea.plugins.path
idea.log.path
```

**EDIT :**

Check this if there is something wrong with your `${user.home}` property

[On Windows 7, how does Java JVM set "user.home" System property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889940/on-windows-7-how-does-java-jvm-set-user-home-system-property)

Comment: Doesnt`t work =(    idea.properties file now contains:  `idea.config.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudioPreview/config` and `idea.system.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudioPreview/system` while in my system `%HOMEPATH% = %USERPROFILE% = "C:\Users\Admin"`

Comment: add something in between the paths like `${user.home}/mypath/.AndroidStudioPreview/config` and `${user.home}/mypath/.AndroidStudioPreview/system` and see where the mypath directory is getting created and let me know.It should be in `"C:\Users\Admin"` if not something wrong with your user home. I don't know it makes difference or not but my `%HOMEPATH%` give me `"\Users\pyus13"` and `%USERPROFILE%` gives me `"C:\Users\pyus13"`

Comment: 1) Now i have `C:\Users\Admin\Dropbox\mypath\.AndroidStudioPreview`
2) I`m sorry. `%HOMEPATH% = "\Users\Admin"` and `%USERPROFILE% = "C:\Users\Admin"`

Comment: Check your regedit value once here `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`

Comment: `Default=%SystemDrive%\Users\Default`, `ProfilesDirectory=%SystemDrive%\Users`, `ProgramData=%SystemDrive%\ProgramData`, `Public=%SystemDrive%\Users\Public`

Comment: Seems fine. I am not getting there is something wrong with your java properties. You can use hard code the complete path instead using {user.home} . Check this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889940/on-windows-7-how-does-java-jvm-set-user-home-system-property , This also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501235/change-user-home-system-property

Comment: Fixed! `KEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\Desktop=C:\Users\Admin\Dropbox\Desktop` I`ve removed `Dropbox` from this path and everything works! @pyus13, thank you!!!