# Gluon Client Build Windows x86_64 fails

Tags: java, javafx, gluon, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I followed all the instructions in Gluon Docs, and when I compile I get a weird

```
[Thu Dec 03 13:16:47 IST 2020][INFO] [SUB] Fatal error:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

How do I fix this?

I am using the latest GraalVM build, latest gluon client plugin.

[Entire output + log](https://gist.github.com/dubbadhar/eba2bc6bec848c454c44e7f1d42443c5)

Comment: Based on your logs, can you check the contents of the jar created under the temp folder, `C:\Users\DEBAYA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\classes1516106915740802479\classes.jar` ? See if it has the JavaFX jars, or post its manifest here?

Comment: @JoséPereda I checked the jar and it contains only classes of my project. No dependencies or javafx jars included. the MANIFEST.MF file just has 

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 11.0.8 (GraalVM Community)
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad, this is the jar you have to check: `C:\Users\DEBAYA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\classpathJar11912885979961198418.jar`

Comment: @JoséPereda https://gist.github.com/dubbadhar/90acceac768b78c36d684b9790ef797a

Comment: Seems you are running into this [issue](https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/issues/813), and the jars in your ~/.gluon path are missed.

Comment: Is there a way to change the location of the `.gluon` folder and put it away into another location? I think my name `Debayan Sutradhar` is causing issues in the path.

Comment: Gluon Substrate [uses](https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/substrate/Constants.java#L35) `user.home` for that. This is how you might override it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1501261/3956070

Comment: @JoséPereda nevermind, I renamed my user name, but now I am getting even more cryptic [errors](https://gist.github.com/dubbadhar/ff029f4bf3a3d451c2fb8a31439feed6). I researched a bit and found [this](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/2420)

Comment: You are running now into "regular" errors when building native image. So this is for another question.

Comment: @JoséPereda here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65123483/unsupported-method-error-gluon-client-for-windows