Change environment variable for executed java program
I have a java program I want to run (that I did not write; I only have the .jar and I execute it with java), and it puts a bunch of gunk in my home directory, so I'd like to export a new home directory when launching this program.
The program is executed through a shell script in /usr/bin like so:
#!/bin/bash

/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin/java \
-jar \
"/usr/share/java/program/prog.jar"

I do not know if it is relevant, but it requires java8, so that is specified there. There are some other options passed to the java command too, but I do not think they are relevant (setting the GC etc.)
I made the following change to try and keep its clutter contained:
#!/bin/bash

export HOME="$HOME/.garbage"

/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin/java \
-jar \
"/usr/share/java/program/prog.jar"

and of course I made sure the directory existed before running the program, but it didn't work and the program kept putting its files in the home directory.
To further test, I tried by replacing java in the script with xterm, and it seemed like the xterm window that opened also didn't inherit the HOME environment variable (because ~ still expanded to my home directory), so I am thinking this may be something to do with how environment variables are handled under X window system.

What kind of "gunk?"   And do you trust the program to do what is intended?

@WJS just state files, but this program either predates XDG or doesn't care to put them in .local/state or anywhere else. Program is completely trusted there's nothing to worry about there, but I cannot edit the program itself by extracting the jar or anything

Try changing user.home property as in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501235/change-user-home-system-property .

That works! Thanks :D

I don't think that Java cares about the setting of the variable HOME. Actually, the variable does not have any magic, except that it is set automatically in a login shell. Try in bash: HOME=/usr/bin; cd. This will still cd you to your home directory, not to /usr/bin. However, bash uses it also for tilde expansion, so cd ~ does get you to /usr/bin.
